# USA visa appointment scheduling

Tags: visas, usa

How can I correct the email I used on my visa appointment? I have sent a mail to them but I have not gotten a response yet.

Also, I filled the bio data section of scheduling the visa appointment twice (internet problem) and now it is giving me issues such that I cannot continue with the appointment scheduling. An identical information prompt came up and I was required to upload a passport which I have done.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Without any information about what type of visa and from where you’re applying, start with a telephone call to your location’s Visa Application Center. If your application is incomplete and you’ve been unable to schedule an interview, contacting the Consulate may not be helpful. Be aware that some of these offices do not respond to emails or fax requests, as a matter of practice.

In the United States, the State Department lists [U.S. Visa Contacts](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/contact-us/us-visas.html) categorized by visa type, as well as an [Embassy/Consulate](https://www.usembassy.gov/) locator.